# Display data in a table from localStorage without repeating

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a shopping list in my web page where I add the items which I store in localStorage.The items are displayed in a table.The problem is that for each new item added it is showing also the data previously stored again.
My html is:

```
<form class="market">
<label>Nume produs</label>
<input type="text" id="np">
<label>Cantitate</label>
<input type="text" id="cp">
<input type="button" onclick="addItem();" id="adauga" value="Adaugă" />

</form>
<table>
<tbody  id="shopping">
<tr>
    <th>Nr.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
```

And this is the function called on every button click

```
class Produs{
constructor(id, nume, cantitate){
    this.id = id;
    this.nume = nume;
    this.cantitate = cantitate;
}
}

function addItem(){
let nume = document.getElementById("np").value;
let cantitate = document.getElementById("cp").value;
let produse = localStorage.getItem('produse');

if(produse == null){
    produse = [];
}
else{
    produse = JSON.parse(produse);
}
produse = produse.map((p) => {
    return new Produs(p.id, p.nume, p.cantitate);
});

let lastId = localStorage.getItem('lastId');
if(lastId == null)
{
    lastId=1;
}
else{
    lastId = JSON.parse(lastId);
}
let id = lastId;
produse.push(new Produs(id, nume, cantitate));
localStorage.setItem('produse',JSON.stringify(produse));
localStorage.setItem('lastId',JSON.stringify(lastId+1));  

var jsonData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('produse'));

console.log(jsonData);

for(var i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++)
{

    document.getElementById("shopping").innerHTML +="<tr><td>"+jsonData[i].id +"</td><td>" + jsonData[i].nume +"</td><td>"+jsonData[i].cantitate+"</td></tr>";  
}
}
```

Comment: So what you do is this here, you get "produse" from local Storage:
let produse = localStorage.getItem('produse');
Then you push a new value to produse
produse.push(new Produs(id, name, candidate)
Then you set the new item in localStorage:
localStorage.setItem('produse',JSON.stringify(produse));

In the next round, you again get the produse without resetting previous values,
you push a new value to it and so on, this causes that no value is ever resetted

Comment: Resetting the localStorage might help

Comment: I am not quite clarified where should I clear it

Comment: Is this java or javascript?

Comment: it is javascript, I chose the wrong tag

Comment: This is javascript @MARSHMALLOW  
I suggest you reset it either after you parsed the data into jsonData by simply deleting the value from localStorage or you delete it at the very top of your function before getting the new localStorage value